# depthmap image png format has 3 dimensions

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a bunch of depth map images which are all png files. I need to use these in matlab. When I use imread, I get the image to have the following dimensions, h*w*3. Since it is a depth map, I think it should have only h and w but since it is in .png format, I think the 3rd dimension is included. How do I convert this back to 2 dimensions? Can I use rgb2gray? Is that sensible and why?

Comment: If the 3 components of each pixel have the same value, `rgb2gray` should return that same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has a 3rd dimension probably because your image is True Color or RGB image.
As [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) say, if you do `rgb2gray` it will give the same picture but as 2D, **only** if all the 3 components are same.  (i.e) only if a gray image is stacked three times as `*.png`, and if you do `rgb2gray` you will obtain the same image without any change but as a 2 Dimension.
Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29448069/2111163) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064144/2111163) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29477529/2111163).